# Does silverlight work on chrome?

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome

Does anyone know if silverlight plugs into chrome, or when they plan to support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This guy have had partial success with silverlight in chrome, but it does not seem to be supported:

http://wildermuth.com/2008/09/02/Silverlight_2_and_Google_Chrome

From The Microsoft Silverlight Team in the [silverlight forum](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/24044.aspx):

> Hello, currently we don't have plans
>   to support Chrome. We will support it
>   in the future if it gains enough
>   market share. Please understand, each
>   browser implements the plug-in model
>   differently, so it'll be a lot of
>   effort to officially support a browser
>   100%... By the way, IE 8 also runs
>   each tab in its own process. If a tab
>   crashes, other tabs will still work
>   fine.

**UPDATE:**

Jon Galloway has just posted instructions on how to get silverlight successfully running on Chrome here:

[http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/09/17/silverlight-on-chrome.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/09/17/running-silverlight-2-on-google-chrome-using-the-chrome-dev-channel.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The official word on what is supported looks like this:

[alt text http://www.jesseliberty.com/sl/browsers.jpg](http://www.jesseliberty.com/sl/browsers.jpg)

The reality is that we do run on **a lot** of browsers, but things change might quickly in these here parts.

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, the Dev Branch of Google Chrome was recently updated to support Silverlight 2.  I tried it and it works for me.  Of course, you have to use the Dev release of Google Chrome.  You can get more information about switching to Chrome Dev [here](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel/).

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight already works with web-kit, and since Google's Chrome is based on web-kit, it shouldn't be too much effort to get it working.

Indeed, [this](http://bits.samiq.net/2008/09/silverlight-and-flash-running-on-google.html) gentleman seems to have had some success.

Based on this, I would suspect that Silverlight will be fully supported by Chrome by the time it goes gold.